# Probability of a specific outcome

Tags: probability

Six of your friends are picking out gifts for you from a gift registry. There are six items on your registry: a toaster, a stereo, a blender, an end table, a waffle maker, and a lamp. Unfortunately, the registry system is malfunctioning and does not take an item off of the list after it has been bought. Thus, it is very possible that you receive multiples of some gifts. While keeping in mind which friend sent which gift, what is the probability that you receive exactly two stereos and exactly one toaster? (Assume all outcomes are equally likely.)

I understand that the number of total outcomes is 6^6 by the multiplication rule, but how do I go about counting the number of possible outcomes of exactly 2 toasters and 1 stereo?

Comment: The total number of possible outcomes is $6^6$ (six friends, six items)

Comment: whoops, yeah, I thought there were 3 items for some reason. thanks. any clue how to find total outcomes that there are 2 toasters and 1 stereo?

Comment: Once you have decided who gave the toasters and who gave the stereo, there are $3$ friends left, each choosing from $4$ gifts.

Comment: So 4 choose 3 should give the total number of outcomes of the scenario that you receive 2 toasters and 1 stereo. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line up your friends by age, or beauty, or student number. Write $T$ for toaster, $B$ for blender, and so on.

Then the possible outcomes can be thought of as the words of length $6$ over this six-letter alphabet. There are $6^6$ such words. We will assume, unreasonably, that they are all equally likely.

How many words have (exactly) $2$ $T$s and $1$ $S$? The location of the $T$s can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. For each such way, the location of the $S$ can be chosen in $\binom{6}{1}$ ways. And once this has been done, the remaining $3$ blank spots can be filled with letters chosen from the remaining $4$ in $4^3$ ways, for a total of $\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{1}4^3$.